# Why isn't this Python JDBC connection working?

Tags: python, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a sybase type DB via the jaydebeapi, but I'm running into problems. I'm getting a strange error when I try to connect and I can't figure out why... Here is the code:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver', ['jdbc:jtds:sybase://hostname:port/database','username','password'],['/home/homedirectory/jtds-1.2.5-dist/jtds-1.2.5.jar'])
```

Here is the error produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testos.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver', ['jdbc:jtds:sybase://hostname:port/','username','password'],['/home/homedirectory/jtds-1.2.5-dist/jtds-1.2.5.jar'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi-0.2.0-py2.6.egg/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 359, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, jars, libs, *driver_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/JayDeBeApi-0.2.0-py2.6.egg/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 183, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(*driver_args)
jpype._jexception.SQLExceptionPyRaisable: java.sql.SQLException: The executeQuery method must return a result set.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" (jtds.jar) just wasn't working for me. When I switched to "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" (jconn4.jar), it started working perfectly. Both drivers are supposed to work, so I assume it's a bug in the net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are probably calling the `executeQuery` function incorrectly or with the wrong type of sql. Try using `execute` instead of `executeQuery`.

Note: This assumes that there is a call to executeQuery that you did not post in you question while still being in your code.

Comment: I get that, but executeQuery is no where to be found in my code. It's literally just the import statement and the conn = statement producing that error. Does that mean the module is broken?

Comment: It may be or you may need an execute statement. You could try another module but I would try adding an execute statement to your code and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see how I can add anything, the error comes after line 2 is executed. I can't do select statements or anything, no matter what I do, it's the same message after line 2 in the code. That's why I only pasted 2 lines.

Comment: So why are you using this module can you not just use another one.

Comment: @Matthew just noticed that you used `[]` on your filepath at the end of line 2 what happens if you remove the `[]`

Comment: I have a sybase module that does indeed work perfectly... But I'm trying to connect to a Netcool Object server which is a little different. JDBC and perl DBI connections are known to work, which is why I'm "trying" to use this module.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it with and without the brackets, but the result is the same.

Comment: Yeah, file path is correct. It gives a "No suitable driver found" error if it isn't correct.